# Embedded ActiveMQ in a Spring Boot application boot does not work properly

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic

Recently, we are trying to use ActiveMQ in our spring boot application. What we did, simply added ActiveMQ dependencies as the below:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-activemq:2.0.4.RELEASE")
```

And the following configuration:

```
#Embedded ActiveMQ Configuration
activemq:
  broker-url: vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false
#Spring JMS Settings
jms:
  listener:
    auto-startup: true
    concurrency: 1
    retries: 4
    exponential-backoff: true
    backoff-multiplier: 5
```

The problem is that when we try to launch the application, we encounter the following warning which apparently means ActiveMQ does not launch properly.

```
2018-10-01 11:53:36.778  WARN 112 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'salesforce-queue' - trying to recover. Cause: peer (vm://localhost#5) stopped.    

2018-10-01 11:53:36.778  WARN 112 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'ActiveMQ.DLQ' - trying to recover. Cause: peer (vm://localhost#7) stopped.
```

I would appreciate it if you share your ideas.